# Codeigniter: Compare a MySql Datetime with Current Date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, codeigniter

I need to compare a MySQL datetime with the current time, to get the dateDiff to show a messange if the MySQL datetime, is less than 30 days from today.

I'm using codeigniter, and I tried a lot of helpers, and lots of thing, I just can't get to work.

Some people says that is better to save in database a timespan, I just don't know wich one is the best aproach.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I'm looking for a CI code, or a Mysql Code, or both, to get it to work. It doesn't matter where i get the current date (could be mysql or server time).
Also, I have the needed code on the view, and the controller, I just need some model code to get it, or MySql code

Comment: What are you looking for, a mySQL query or CI code?

Comment: Any of those... Even advise on how to get it to work.

Comment: Why don't you show us your code?

Comment: I'm calling it a day for today so I can't write a full solution but what you need will be possible to do using the [mySQL Date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html): `NOW()` / `DATE_SUB()` / `DATE_ADD()`/ maybe `DATE_DIFF()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),your_mysql_date_field) FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the PHP [date_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function, for example:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%d days');
```

The above example will output:

```
+2 days
```

You can get the current time using [getdate()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php).